# How to enlarge the reading pane font in Office 365 (Outlook)?

Tags: ms-office

The font is too small on the reading pane of Outlook 2016. Is there a hack to enlarge the reading pane font? I've had Macs for years but then Helvetica Neue font is too small for me.

Answer (score 3):

While in the reading pane of Outlook 2016 click **Format >  Increase Font Size** or press <kbd>command⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> on your keyboard.

This should increase the font size of the message content in the Reading Pane.

Comment: This does indeed work.  Command - will decrease it. Unfortunately this is not persistent and Outlook does not remember the setting.  However the OP can send Microsoft some feedback regarding the issue.